# Describe the closure in the Zariski topology

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry

I have a little bit to fight with the Zariski - topology. In $\mathbb{C}^2$, i have to describe by a finite number of polynomial equations the Zariski closure of:

1. $C:= \{(n,n^2) \in \mathbb{C}^2 : n \in \mathbb{N} \}$
2. $D:= \mathbb{C}^2 \setminus \{(0,0)\}  $.

We can use the fact that for $M \in \mathbb{C}^n: Z(I(M))= \bar{M}$, where $\bar{M}$ denotes the closure of $M$ in the Zariski topology.

> 1. Denote $x = n$ and $y = n^2$. It follows
>      $$
>     x^2 - y = 0 \Rightarrow x^2 - y \in I(C) \Rightarrow \bar{C} = Z(I(C)) \subsetneq \mathbb{C}^2,
>    $$
>      since $I(C) \neq {0}$.

So now i don't know how to find a finite number of polynomial equation. I think, but i am not sure, that we can conclude that $I(C) = (x^2 -y)$ and thus $\bar{C} = Z((x^2-y))$. Am i right?

> 2. Suppose $D\subseteq Z(J)$ for an ideal $J \subseteq \mathbb{C}[X,Y]$ and $f \in J$ with $f(a) = 0 \ \forall a \in D$.

I think we can't deduce that $f$ is the zero polynomial. But my intuition says that $\bar{D} = Z(I(D)) = \mathbb{C}^2$. Where is/are my mistake/s? 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: The answer to 1 has to be the $Z(x^2-y)$.  It is a closed set and the only closed sets contained in it are the finite subsets, none of which contains your set $C$, so the closure must be the whole of $Z(x^2-y)$.

Comment: You are right on part 2 as well, the only proper closed subsets of $\Bbb C^2$ are finite unions of curves and points.

Comment: Thx for your comment. 
1. How we can conclude from $x^2-y \in I(C) \Rightarrow I(C) = (x^2-y)$?
2.  Sry, but i do not understand your argument for my intuition. Because "the only proper closed subsets of C2 are finite unions of curves and points" thus we can conclude that $\bar{D} = Z(I(D)) = \mathbb{C}^2$?

Comment: Re 2, $\mathbb C^2$ is irreducible. The given subset is open, so it must be dense.

Comment: Ah, thats a good point @AymanHourieh. And for 1.) I know why we can conlude this: apriori we know that $(x^2 - y) \subset I(C)$. But since $x^2 - y$ is irreducible we obtain $(x^2-y) = I(C)$.

Comment: That doesn't make sense. Note that $Z(x^2 - y)$ is homeomorphic to $\operatorname{Spec} k[x, y] / (x^2 - y) \cong \mathbb A_k^1$. As @GregoryGrant pointed out, since all proper closed subsets of $\mathbb A_k^1$ are finite, it follows that $Z(x^2 - y)$ is the smallest closed subset that contains $C$ (an infinite set).

Comment: We have not define $\mathrm{Spec}$ yet. Can you describe the second sentence in another way?

Comment: Do you know how to show that $Z(x^2 - y)$ as a variety is isomorphic to the affine line?

Comment: It's not really necessary, $Z(x^2-y)$ is an irreducible curve in the plane, so its proper closed subsets are $Z(x^2-y)\cap Z(f(x,y))$ where $f$ is another polynomial.  Those are just the finite subsets.

Comment: @AymanHourieh i know from the lecutre that 
$$
\mathbb{k}[V(x^2-y)] \simeq \mathbb{k}[X,Y]/(x^2 - y) \simeq \mathbb{k}[X].
$$
But i think this do not answer your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps the issue is that you're not comfortable with the Nullstellensatz and dimension theory?

Here's how to do the first problem.

For 1 you've shown that $\overline{C} \subseteq V(y-x^2)$.  Since $k[x,y]/(y-x^2) \cong k[x,x^2] = k[x]$ is an integral domain, the ideal $(y-x^2)$ is prime, and hence the parabola $V(y-x^2)$ is irreducible.  Moreover, it is isomorphic to the affine line $\mathbb{A}^1$, and hence one-dimensional.  By the Nullstellensatz, then, any closed set properly contained in $V(y-x^2)$ is zero-dimensional, and hence a finite union of points.  Such a set can't contain all of $C$, so $V(y-x^2)$ is indeed the closure of $C$.

Of course, this is using a fairly sophisticated understanding of algebraic geometry to establish that the curve is actually one-dimensional.  Depending on how you're doing the class you may not have access to this machinery (namely, that dimension and affine-ness are intrinsic notions and that an affine variety may be recovered (up to isomorphism) from its coordinate ring), and consequently may have to establish the dimension of $V(y-x^2)$ in some other way.

Comment: Thank you for the great explanation. :)